# Date query works in Mongo shell but not from Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I run the following query from the Mongo shell, it works fine:

```
db.reports.find({
  dateTime: { 
    $gte: "2018-06-12T05:00:00.000Z",
    $lte: "2018-06-15T05:00:00.000Z",
  }
}
```

gives the result:

```
{ 
  "_id" : "5b3eaf388213fa2f5026ed26", 
  "report_id" : "1", 
  "description": "test description 1",
  "address" : "300-BLK Hilliard Ave",
  dateTime" : "2018-06-13T04:00:00.000Z"
},
{ 
  "_id" : "5b3eaf388213fa2f5026ed27", 
  "report_id" : "2", 
  "description": "test description 2",
  "address" : "1600-BLK Patton Ave",
  dateTime" : "2018-06-13T04:00:00.000Z"
},
{ 
  "_id" : "5b3eaf388213fa2f5026ed28", 
  "report_id" : "3", 
  "description": "test description 3",
  "address" : " ",
  dateTime" : "2018-06-14T04:00:00.000Z"
}
```

but when I try executing it in a Node script, it returns an empty array:

```
reportModel.find({
  dateTime: { 
    $gte: "2018-06-12T05:00:00.000Z",
    $lte: "2018-06-15T05:00:00.000Z",
  }, (err, reports) => {
    if (err) {
      reject(err) 
    }
    resolve(reports)
}
```

I know it is connecting to the database because the queries I run on other properties all return the expected values.

My `report` model is:

```
const report = new mongoose.Schema({
  report_id: { type: String, default: '' }
  description: { type: String, default: '' }      
  address: { type: String, default: '' }
  dateTime: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

I've tried various wrappings of `new Date()` and `new ISODate()` as suggested in various answers here to no avail. Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: can you share your reportModel?

Comment: @mehta-rohan I've added it.

Comment: share result of mongo shell

Comment: Added mongo shell results too

Comment: If that query works in the shell, then `dateTime` should be defined as a `String` in your schema, not a `Date`.

Comment: are you able to fetch data from node script without query part.

Comment: @JohnnyHK That solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @mehta-rohan I can get data with different queries or no query.

Comment: reportModel.find({}, (err, reports) => { if (err) { reject(err) } resolve(reports) }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data types in your Mongoose schema needs to match what's in the saved documents. So because the query works in the shell, your `dateTime` field must be a string in your documents, and your schema definition should look like:

```
const report = new mongoose.Schema({
  report_id: { type: String, default: '' }
  description: { type: String, default: '' }      
  address: { type: String, default: '' }
  dateTime: { type: String, default: Date.now }
})
```

However, you may want to consider storing your `dateTime` values as `Date` for better efficiency and flexibility.

Comment: Initially it was a date object, but it changed when I dumped the DB contents into a .json file and imported the file into another database. Guess I should get an actual database dump......